# Keyword analyzer for product-codes

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to implement a search index for some products, where their product-code should be searchable using wildcards.
An example of such a product-code could be something like this: `TTY1012-0088-VTX1`.

I have the set up the product-code field to be searchable and use the `keyword` analyzer.
(Using the [test analyzer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) I can see that the product-code is tokenized as one token.)

But when I try to search for the product, using the Azure Cognitive Search Explorer, with this query: `queryType=full&search=/TTY-10.*/`, nothing is found.
Notice that I am using a Lucene regex query for the search and the search query contains a hyphen (`-`)!

What am I doing wrong since I can't get this search to return anything?

---

**NOTE**

I can read, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28811181/4755799), that when using the `keyword` analyzer, only exact match searches are possible.
I have not been able find anything saying this is true in the official documentation, so is it correct?

---

**EDIT 1**

After working a bit more with the problem, it seems like it is hyphens in the product-codes that is the problem.
If the wildcard search includes a hyphen, no result are found.
The question have been updated with this detail.

I have thought about solving the problem by removing hyphens from the product-code and incoming search requests.

Answer (score 1):

as per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-query-partial-matching), For regular expression, wildcard, and fuzzy search, analyzers aren't used at query time. For these query forms, which the parser detects by the presence of operators and delimiters, the query string is passed to the engine without lexical analysis. For these query forms, the analyzer specified on the field is ignored. In this case, this applies to the analyzer "keyword" you are using.

You can use "keyword" in one of your fields and in another one use one with Standard Lucene so your wildcard query works.

If you search for TTY* if you are using the Standard Lucene analyzer, since it will tokenize as needed, your query should work. Here is part of the index definition with both analyzers:

[image: Part of the index definition]

Here is the wildcard query you're trying to get that product code for:

[image: Wildcard query]

Here is one you'll get with the whole product code since you have the keyword to include the dashes as well:

[image: Full name]

[Edited adding the below to adjust to the question latest edit as well]:
If you use the same advisory without using the wildcard, but only the partial term, this same configuration will work. Example:

[image: Partial term with hyphen]

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gia! I don't think my question was precise enough so I have updated it with additional information.
I am still not able to perform the wildcard search you describe, if it contains a hyphen (`-`).

Comment: You're welcome! The response has also been edited. If you use the analyzers as I suggested to have the full term and also the Lucene analyzer in a separate field so you can do full term search or partial, it should work, without wildcard, the partial term even if including hyphens should get you the response you need.